# Di Ritorno (I think?)

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, language

I am return.

In other news, use Eurovision rankings.

Also, here's the weekly spelling list (etymologies inclusive):

psephology, Greek

caixinha, Portuguese

auftaktigkeit, German

gopak, Russ. from Ukrainian

bocaccio, Italian

barramundi, native Australian

Oświęcim, Polish

mariengroschen, Dutch

Bruxellois, Belgian geog. name

*What am I trying to tell you?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the message here is:

> **HIYA FOLKS** - an appropriate message from somebody returning to the website after some time away.

Since the puzzle includes the line '*use Eurovision rankings*', we should probably take a look at...

> ...this year's Eurovision results:
>
>  [image: Eurovision 2022 final leaderboard]

If we then...

> ...replace each European country reference in the 'spelling list' with that country's ranking on the leaderboard, we extract the following numbers:
>
>  Greece = 8
>  Portugal = 9
>  Germany = 25
>  Ukraine = 1
>  Italy = 6
>  Australia = 15
>  Poland = 12
>  Netherlands = 11
>  Belgium = 19
>
>  All that remains is to interpret these numbers using A1Z26, spelling out the message **HIYA FOLKS**.
>
>  (I believe the words in the spelling list are themselves merely distractions and contribute nothing more to the puzzle...)